# Autocomplete on textbox returing 404 error , controller/action not found

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to integrate `autocomplete` on my `textbox`. But it's not hitting the `action` method to fetch the data from model. It throws the following error in console:

> http://localhost:56393/Api/AutoCompleteChannelName 404 (Not Found)

Below is the .cshtml code :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

JavaScript:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#channelName").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Api/AutoCompleteChannelName",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: { term: request.term },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.ChannelName,

                        };
                    }))
                }
            })
        },

        select: function (event, ui) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $("#channelName").val(ui.item.label);
            $("#hdnChannelName").val(ui.item.label);
        },

        messages: {
            noResults: "", results: ""
        }
    });
```

Input tag :

```
<input id="channelName" class="form-control" value="" name="channelName" placeholder="Enter Channel Name To Filter" />
```

ActionResult :

```
public JsonResult AutoCompleteChannelName(string term)
    {

        List<DIM_CHANNEL> obj = bc.DIM_CHANNEL.Where(m => m.CHANNEL_NAME.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(i => new DIM_CHANNEL
        {
            ChannelName = i.CHANNEL_NAME,
            ChannelKey = i.CHANNEL_KEY,
        }).ToList();

        return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: what is the controller class name?

Comment: use helper method of Url : ``url: `@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")'``

Comment: Controller is API and the action method is AutoCompleteChannelName

Comment: @N2J, Please do not accept answers which have nothing to do with your issue - it just misleads other users

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first of all, change `POST` to `GET`. Also, do you have WebAPI route defined in your `WebApiConfig.cs`?

If it does, you either need to remove that routing, or rename your Controller to anything other than `APIController`

Comment: I changed POST TO GET and the changed the controller name and it works..so happy..Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the type of your ajax call to GET

```
$.ajax({
            url: "/Api/AutoCompleteChannelName",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { term: request.term },
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.ChannelName,

                    };
                }))
            }
        })
```

Answer (score -1):

you missed

```
[HttpGet]
```

attribute in your jsonresult method.

please refer the following code hope it works for you:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult AutoCompleteChannelName(string term)
        {

            List<DIM_CHANNEL> obj = bc.DIM_CHANNEL.Where(m => m.CHANNEL_NAME.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower())).Distinct().AsEnumerable().Select(i => new DIM_CHANNEL
            {
                ChannelName = i.CHANNEL_NAME,
                ChannelKey = i.CHANNEL_KEY,
            }).ToList();

            return Json(obj, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: as far as I am confirmed if the httpget is not there , it is considered default a get method method. however I tried by putting httpget but still not hitting the method.

Comment: ok
then please try again with
removing 
type: "POST",
dataType: "json",
from your script.

surely it helps.
Thanks

Comment: I changed the post type to get and changed the controller name ,and it works.. Thanks :)